# Python for loop. Extract specific value from AWS

Tags: python, for-loop, boto3

I'm trying to get a for loop to work in boto3 and even though I have it working, it was hard to figure it out. At the moment I have:

```
  `spot_requests = ec2.describe_spot_instance_requests()
   for index in spot_requests['SpotInstanceRequests']:
        instanceID = index["InstanceId"]
        instanceState = index["State"]
        spotRequestID = index["SpotInstanceRequestId"]

    print(f'{instanceID} is {instanceState} and has a request ID of {spotRequestID}')`
```

which returns something like:

"I-1234556 IS disabled and has a request ID of sir-12344"

what I don't understand is why the index needs to be there after the = sign and why it errors if I just have:

`instanceID = ["InstanceId"]`

Also, I understand how dictionaries work, you reference the dictionary name and then in [square brackets] the key that you want to find the value for. However, when I try this (which is correct apparently)

```
    `describe_instance = ec2.describe_instances()
     for item2 in describe_instance['Reservations']:
        instance_state = item2['Instances'][0]["State"]["Name"]`
```

I don't understand what the [0] is doing as there is no key in the dictionary with 0 value. And what would I do if there was a nested dictionary in this? would it be something like this:

```
describe_instance = ec2.describe_instances()
 for item2 in describe_instance['Reservations']:
     instance_state = item2['Instances'][0]["State"]["Name"][0]["Nested value I want to find"]
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I don't understand is why the index needs to be there after the = sign and why it errors if I just have:

"index" is there because that is the dict that you want to get the specified value from.

> I don't understand what the [0] is doing as there is no key in the dictionary with 0 value.

The [<number>] syntax indicates that you are trying to get a value from a a list, where the number indicates which index in the list you want to get. In you specific case the 'Instances' object in item2 is a list of dicts containing information about all the EC2 instances. Which is why you can use ['State']['Name'] to get the name of the state that the instance is currently in.

> And what would I do if there was a nested dictionary in this? would it be something like this:

If the 'Name' field would contain a list of dicts (which wouldn't make sense) then you could do what you are suggesting in your last example.

Comment: so the 'index' is saying from the index dic get the 'state','instanceID', etc?

And for the second point with the [0], do you mean that the first line:
describe_instance = ec2.describe_instances() 
-- returns a dictionary and the for loop -- 
for item2 in describe_instance['Reservations']: 

returns a list? and so the [0] is then getting the first value from that list that has the name of 'State'? thanks very much

Comment: `describe_instance['Reservations']` returns a dict which gets assigned to item2. The 'Instances' object within that dict is a list though. A list of dicts, which is why you can perform `['State']` on it to get the State dict. In that dict there is a field called 'Name' which is what you are getting with the last `['Name']`.

Comment: thank you very much isak. my apologies but in regards to the [0], when that entire value is returned the start of it looks as follows:
{'Reservations': [{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex' ....
so what I don't quite get is shouldn't the ['Instances'][0] return back 'AmiLaunchIndex'.
thank you though I understand the rest of it, how it gets the inside dictionary, but I still don't fully understand this step

Comment: You are almost correct. As you can see by the square brackets and curly brackets 'Instances' is also a list of dicts ('Instances': **[{**'AmiLaunchIndex' ...). When you perform `['Instances'][0]` you are getting the dict at index 0 in that list. From that dict you are then getting the State attribute (from which you are finally getting the Name).

Comment: oh I see, thank you. So its like there is an invisible dict name in between the [ and { and the ['Instances'][0] is getting this name. Would that be correct? Thank you very much isak

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be one way of thinking about it. Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question. :)